# Swipe between page ionic/angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm doing a mobile app with ionic angular 2.

I would like to be able to switch page by swipping.

For example I would like to be able to navigate between the tabs by swipping with the finger.
And I have a page "Calendar" that lists upcoming events. I want to separate event by month, and be able to switch month by swipping.

Do you have any idea ?

The solutions I found do not work. Is there something new?

Answer (score 0):

Thats quite a big question, and I think you'll battle to get a definitive "answer" on SO. I'd suggest you have a look at HammerJS, a widely used gesture support JS library that integrates neatly with the built in gesture support in Angular.

**Some useful references to get started:**

HammerJS getting started docs - https://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/

Scotch.io article describing how to integrate HammerJS and Angular - https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2

*Its worth noting that the **Angular Material** project uses HammerJS for its gesture support. This means its very likely that this integration will be well supported going forward.*

Comment: Thank you, i will take a look

Comment: No problem. Please upvote/mark as answer if you find this helpful.